# PHP preg_match does not return all values as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have strings like:

1. postGeneratePasswordToken
2. putUsers_VAL_Calculations_NUMBER_
3. deleteUsers_VAL_Clients_ID_
4. getDictionary_VAL_

the result i'm expecting is array (array per example above) with elements like below:

1. post, Generate, Password, Token
2. get, Users, _VAL_, Calculations, _NUMBER_
3. delete, Users, _VAL_, Clients, _ID_
4. get, Dictionary, _VAL_

below is my code:

```
$regex = '#(post|get|put|delete)(([A-Z][a-z]+)|(_[A-Z]{2,}_))+#';

$nameArray = preg_match_all($regex, $methodName, $matches);
```

and example output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "putUsers_VAL_Calculations_NUMBER_"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "put"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "_NUMBER_"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Calculations"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "_NUMBER_"
  }
}
```

I know my regex works fine (checked with diffrent testers), but I have no Idea how to fix that, I've read documentation for preg_match, and It's not helpful since It's olny do return  per group in regex. Any Idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: FYI Added online demo to my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any Idea how I can solve this problem?`

Yes, you can use `preg_split` like this:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?=_[A-Z]*_)|(?<=_)(?=[A-Z][a-z])/', $str);
```

The $result array has the strings you want.

The idea is that the regex used by `preg_split` does not match a string; rather, it matches a position in the string. This position is defined by lookarounds so it has zero characters.

This code produces the arrays you want (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/BuHgyO)):

```
<?php
$regex = "~(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?=_[A-Z]*_)|(?<=_)(?=[A-Z][a-z])~";
print_r(preg_split($regex,"postGeneratePasswordToken"));
print_r(preg_split($regex,"putUsers_VAL_Calculations_NUMBER_"));
print_r(preg_split($regex,"deleteUsers_VAL_Clients_ID_"));
print_r(preg_split($regex,"getDictionary_VAL_"));
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?<=                     # look behind to see if there is:
  [a-z]                  #   any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)                        # end of look-behind
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  [A-Z]                  #   any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)                        # end of look-ahead
|                        # OR
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  _                      #   '_'
  [A-Z]*                 #   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  _                      #   '_'
)                        # end of look-ahead
|                        # OR
(?<=                     # look behind to see if there is:
  _                      #   '_'
)                        # end of look-behind
(?=                      # look ahead to see if there is:
  [A-Z]                  #   any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
  [a-z]                  #   any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)                        # end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Well, that is solution for my problem. It's good that you explained regex (I know how it works but it's good for future viewers)

Comment: @AdrianModliszewski Glad to hear it works for you, thanks for letting me know. :)